# How to dismiss UIPopover ONLY if i press the button?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, dismiss, uipopover

Now my popover  dismissing if i press anywhere on the screen, but i need to show and hide him only if i press the button(the same button), how can i do these? Thank you.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @Ashwin Ganesh K, i try do write in my button smth like [Popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; but it's useless, because if i tab a button, or better say try to tap, because in fact i can't press it, popover hides, and only after i can press my button. Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a delegate to your `UIPopoverController` and implement the following method:

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
     return NO;
}
```

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPopoverControllerDelegate):

> This method is called in response to user-initiated attempts to dismiss the popover. It is not called when you dismiss the popover using the `dismissPopoverAnimated:` method of the popover controller.
>
> If you do not implement this method in your delegate, the default return value is assumed to be `YES`.